# Not able to create a resource in demo.ckan.org through the API (500 error)

Tags: ckan

I'm doing some tests with `demo.ckan.org`, which is running the 2.4 version of the API, AFAIK. Everything works well (organization and dataset creation) except for the resource creation. The `resource_create` method always returns a `500` error.

This is the `curl` showing the package where I want to create the resource:

```
$ curl -X GET "http://demo.ckan.org:80/api/3/action/package_show?id=f2c4125b-27c8-4e07-94d7-d6d0c0b65154" | python -m json.tool
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1228  100  1228    0     0   1384      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1386
{
    "help": "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/help_show?name=package_show",
    "result": {
        "author": null,
        "author_email": null,
        "creator_user_id": "b0a12b23-4cee-4d8c-993e-723421a0a296",
        "extras": [],
        "groups": [],
        "id": "f2c4125b-27c8-4e07-94d7-d6d0c0b65154",
        "isopen": false,
        "license_id": null,
        "license_title": null,
        "maintainer": null,
        "maintainer_email": null,
        "metadata_created": "2015-09-29T14:09:21.629953",
        "metadata_modified": "2015-09-29T14:09:21.669256",
        "name": "frb_org_test1_frb_pkg_test2",
        "notes": null,
        "num_resources": 0,
        "num_tags": 0,
        "organization": {
            "approval_status": "approved",
            "created": "2015-09-29T10:55:53.479724",
            "description": "",
            "id": "402f83c1-0070-4694-a1d9-f25b1d114631",
            "image_url": "",
            "is_organization": true,
            "name": "frb_org_test1",
            "revision_id": "26993878-9024-429a-b753-cc087b0ce382",
            "state": "active",
            "title": "",
            "type": "organization"
        },
        "owner_org": "402f83c1-0070-4694-a1d9-f25b1d114631",
        "private": false,
        "relationships_as_object": [],
        "relationships_as_subject": [],
        "resources": [],
        "revision_id": "47acfd70-8d26-4ebb-8cbd-6cababc627b1",
        "state": "active",
        "tags": [],
        "title": "frb_org_test1_frb_pkg_test2",
        "type": "dataset",
        "url": null,
        "version": null
    },
    "success": true
}
```

And the `curl` failing when trying to create the resource:

```
$ curl -X POST "http://demo.ckan.org:80/api/3/action/resource_create" -d '{ "name": "room1_room", "url": "none", "package_id": "f2c4125b-27c8-4e07-94d7-d6d0c0b65154" }' -H "Authorization: MY_API_KEY_IS_SECRET"
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator,
 [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred,
and anything you might have done that may have
caused the error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at demo.ckan.org Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is without access to the logs. An alternative is to use package_show, add a new resource dict to the resources list and then call package_update.

Comment: Cool, that would be a good workaround. Sadly, it is mandatory for me the resource_create method works.

Comment: I've asked for the logs from the server (on IRC), hopefully they'll shed some light on the subject.  It's clearly an issue rather than something you were doing wrong as I managed to replicate it quite easily.

Comment: Perfect, I'll be waiting for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a documentation (and code) bug.

Although format is marked as optional in the documentation, the code requires it to be present (and will unfortunately crash if it isn't).

I've created a ticket at https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/2665

As a temporary measure until this is fixed, you can specify the "format" in the JSON you send (it can be empty).

Comment: It works, many thanks! Now the problem is another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881002/no-view-created-for-a-resource-at-demo-ckan-org