# No view created for a resource at demo.ckan.org

Tags: ckan

Once my [resource creation problem has been solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860432/not-able-to-create-a-resource-in-demo-ckan-org-through-the-api-500-error), I have another problem with demo.ckan.org.

After creating the resource, I've created a datastore and upserted some data:

```
POST http://demo.ckan.org:80/api/3/action/resource_create HTTP/1.1
{"help": "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/help_show?name=resource_create", "success": true, "result": {"cache_last_updated": null, "cache_url": null, "mimetype_inner": null, "hash": "", "description": "", "format": "", "url": "http://none", "created": "2015-10-01T06:18:25.471301", "state": "active", "webstore_last_updated": null, "webstore_url": null, "package_id": "51b379eb-a2a4-49d8-89b3-188dafdd0279", "last_modified": null, "mimetype": null, "url_type": null, "position": 0, "revision_id": "75c80743-66a8-49d2-a01f-ad67734386f5", "size": null, "id": "12eab044-7853-4907-9879-872550f1376b", "resource_type": null, "name": "room1_room"}}

POST http://demo.ckan.org:80/api/3/action/datastore_create HTTP/1.1
{"help": "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_create", "success": true, "result": {"fields": [{"type": "int", "id": "recvTimeTs"}, {"type": "timestamp", "id": "recvTime"}, {"type": "text", "id": "entityId"}, {"type": "text", "id": "entityType"}, {"type": "text", "id": "attrName"}, {"type": "text", "id": "attrType"}, {"type": "json", "id": "attrValue"}, {"type": "json", "id": "attrMd"}], "method": "insert", "resource_id": "12eab044-7853-4907-9879-872550f1376b"}}

POST http://demo.ckan.org:80/api/3/action/datastore_upsert HTTP/1.1
{"help": "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_upsert", "success": true, "result": {"records": [{"attrType": "centigrade", "recvTime": "2015-10-01T06:18:24.72Z", "recvTimeTs": "1443680304", "attrValue": "26.5", "entityType": "Room", "attrName": "temperature", "entityId": "Room1"}], "method": "insert", "resource_id": "12eab044-7853-4907-9879-872550f1376b"}}
```

The data is there, it can be retrieved through the `datastore_search`:

```
curl -s -S -H "Authorization: b4f6cd71-b592-49a3-bb85-9cd5a0f2eb68" "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=12eab044-7853-4907-9879-872550f1376b"
{"help": "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_search", "success": true, "result": {"resource_id": "12eab044-7853-4907-9879-872550f1376b", "fields": [{"type": "int4", "id": "_id"}, {"type": "int4", "id": "recvTimeTs"}, {"type": "timestamp", "id": "recvTime"}, {"type": "text", "id": "entityId"}, {"type": "text", "id": "entityType"}, {"type": "text", "id": "attrName"}, {"type": "text", "id": "attrType"}, {"type": "json", "id": "attrValue"}, {"type": "json", "id": "attrMd"}], "records": [{"attrType": "centigrade", "recvTime": "2015-10-01T06:18:24.720000", "recvTimeTs": 1443680304, "attrMd": null, "attrValue": "26.5", "entityType": "Room", "attrName": "temperature", "entityId": "Room1", "_id": 1}], "_links": {"start": "/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=12eab044-7853-4907-9879-872550f1376b", "next": "/api/3/action/datastore_search?offset=100&resource_id=12eab044-7853-4907-9879-872550f1376b"}, "total": 1}}
```

Nevetheless, the demo.ckan.org says:

> There are no views created for this resource yet.
>
> Not seeing the views you were expecting? Click here for more information.
>
> Here are some reasons you may not be seeing expected views:
>
> - No view has been created that is suitable for this resource
> - The site administrators may not have enabled the relevant view plugins
> - If a view requires the DataStore, the DataStore plugin may not be enabled, or the data may not have been pushed to the DataStore, or the DataStore hasn't finished processing the data yet

I've always been working with the 2.2 API, and no view had to be created. Now, it seems I have to create such a view with 2.4 API. Is it correct and I have to use the `http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.4.0/api/index.html#ckan.logic.action.create.resource_view_create` method? Or is it simply a problem with the portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views aren't automatically created for resource data created directly in the datastore like this. The creation is triggered by resource create assuming there is some data there, but you create an empty resource and add data to it later. As recommended in the other answer, the best route would be to use the API.

Comment: I had to leave this issue for a time, now I'm back. Which are the available view types? I cannot find them in the doc. Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/data-viewer.html#available-view-plugins

By the way, if you are trying to add views using the user interface for a datastore resource, you'll need to 'trick' CKAN into believing that the data can be visualized by adding a format in the resource edit form, the best choice is usually CSV.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I already found it, nevertheless, I cannot figure out how to create the Json payload required for each view type. I mean, I've tested this `curl -s -S -H "Authorization: my-api-key" "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/resource_view_create?resource_id=eaf95b46-3a9f-4cbc-87cf-a6364e9581b1&title=view_test&view_type=recline_view"` and I got `"Bad request - JSON Error: No request body data"`. Any hints?

Comment: Instead of using arguments in the URL, use the -d switch, e.g.:
curl -s -S -H "Authorization: my-api-key" "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/resource_view_create" -d '{"resource_id": "eaf95b46-3a9‌​f-4cbc-87cf-a6364e9581b1",  "title": "view_test", "view_type": "recline_view"}'

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that it is the way that the demo server is set up, I'd suggest using the API call to create the resource_view yourself (unless you have control of the server and configure it differently) is the way to go.

Comment: I had to leave this issue for a time, now I'm back. Which are the available view types? I cannot find them in the doc. Thanks!